# Express Nodejs: Static Files Multiple Directories. One of them only allowing .png requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My goal in my NodeJS Express app is to have 2 static directories.

Every file in the first directory (/client) is accessible.

Only .png files in the second directory (/quest) are accessible.

This is what I tried to do:

```
app.use(/\/quest\/.*\.png/,express.static('quest')); //doesnt work

app.use(express.static('client')); //works correctly



//Note: This will actually trigger the messages
app.use(/\/quest\/.*\.png/,function(){
    console.log(100);
});
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why but `app.use` syntax for some reason only matches the route, it doesn't set the `req.url` to the requested URL which is required by `express.static` to look for the specified file. `app.VERB` syntax is better suited to handle routes.

Then since you're already telling `express.static` to look into `/quest` directory, you need to strip that from the `req.url` or otherwise it'll look for `/quest` `/quest/file.png`

```
app.get('/quest/*.png', function(req, res, next) {
    req.url = req.url.replace('/quest','');
    next();
}, express.static('quest'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Verified that laggingreflex's solution works on express 4.13.0